# Смена фонового изображения веб-страницы анимацией CSS

Tags: css

Есть смена фона веб-страницы посредством css-анимации. Можно ли в ключевых кадрах писать разные изображения. Получилось что-то не очень.

```css
.csa-head {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: changeBackground 12s infinite linear,fadeToggle 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes changeBackground{
  0%{
    background-image: url(images/photo-1485178575877-1a13bf489dfe.jpg);
  }
  33.33%{
    background-image: url(images/photo-1512521743077-a42eeaaa963c.jpg);
  }
  66.66%{
    background-image: url(images/dfgsdfgsdfg.JPG);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeToggle{
  0%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  50%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно объединить их в один большой анимасьон (спойлер: Задротство)

[( JsFiddle )](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/yx3tg1Lw/)

```css
body::after {
  display: none;
  content: url('https://www.rollingstone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rammstein_JensKoch_3105_hires.jpg') url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2095947.jpg') url('https://seberrow.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/amberian-dawn.jpg');
}
/* Это чтобы заранее картинки подгрузились и не "мигали" на первом круге. */

.csa-head {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: changeBackground 12s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes changeBackground{
  0%{
    background-image: url('https://www.rollingstone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rammstein_JensKoch_3105_hires.jpg');
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('https://www.rollingstone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rammstein_JensKoch_3105_hires.jpg');
  }
  28% { opacity: 0; }
  30.3% { opacity: 0; }
  33.3%{
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2095947.jpg');
  }
  58.3%{
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2095947.jpg');
  }
  61.3% { opacity: 0; }
  63.3% { opacity: 0; }
  66.3%{
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('https://seberrow.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/amberian-dawn.jpg');
  }
  91.3%{
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('https://seberrow.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/amberian-dawn.jpg');
  }
  94.3% { opacity: 0; }
  96.9% { opacity: 0; }
  99.99%{
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('https://www.rollingstone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rammstein_JensKoch_3105_hires.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="csa-head"></div>
```

P.s. но это для примера. В реальной жизни ставить изменение фона раз в 4 секунды - садизм. Хотя бы раз в 5 минут, если очень хочется))